# flutter android app crashing on prod build

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am running the build command for my project to check release mode locally before it gets pushed, everything runs fine then the app got lunched and closed immediately when running this command:

`flutter run --release --flavor prod`

and it's failing with this error message :

```dart
Launching lib/main.dart on I4113 in release mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleProdRelease'...                            
Running Gradle task 'assembleProdRelease'... Done                  35.0s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-prod-release.apk (32.6MB).
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...                 5.4s

Flutter run key commands.
h Repeat this help message.
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
E/AndroidRuntime(31478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(31478): Process: io.rev PID: 31478
E/AndroidRuntime(31478): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method a()Ljava/lang/String; in class Landroid/content/res/XmlResourceParser; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(Unknown Source:39)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7045)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6590)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6485)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1865)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:359)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7418)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime(31478):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Answer (score 2):

R8 removed the class on release. Try adding those lines to your `app/proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-dontnote org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.xmlpull.** { *; }
```

`app/build.gradle` :

```
release {
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
        'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```